# How do I break a promise chain?

Tags: javascript

How should I stop the promise chain in this case?
Execute the code of second then only when the condition in the first then is true.

```
var p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(function() {
        resolve(1)
    }, 0);
});

p
.then((res) => {
    if(true) {
        return res + 2
    } else {
        // do something and break the chain here ???
    }
})
.then((res) => {
    // executed only when the condition is true
    console.log(res)
})
```

Comment: Would just throwing an error here work for your use-case? You wouldn't get into your next then if you throw any type of error (even just `throw new Error();` should probably work)

Comment: Yes I know, but it will break the promise chain and thus not hit the next then. If that is all he is trying to do, this will work

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can `throw` an `Error` in the `else` block, then `catch` it at the end of the promise chain:

```
var p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(function() {
        resolve(1)
    }, 0);
});

p
.then((res) => {
    if(false) {
        return res + 2
    } else {
        // do something and break the chain here ???
      throw new Error('error');
    }
})
.then((res) => {
    // executed only when the condition is true
    console.log(res)
})
.catch(error => {
  console.log(error.message);
})
```

Demo - https://jsbin.com/ludoxifobe/edit?js,console

Comment: Is there any other way to stop it? because my code in the else block is not supposed to be an 'error'

Comment: @vincentf yes, `return Promise.reject('some messeage or not');` in else.

Comment: In JS, you may throw any value, not just error. `throw value`. There's no difference between `return Promise.reject(value)` and `throw value` in promises.

Answer (score 0):

You could read [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then#Return_value), which says

> `Promise.then` return a rejected Promise if the input function throws an error, or the input function returns a rejected Promise.

If you prefer, you could read the [Promise A spec](https://promisesaplus.com/), in the section about `then`, where `promise2` refers to the resulting promise:

> If either `onFulfilled` or `onRejected` throws an exception `e`, `promise2` must be rejected with e as the reason.)

If you prefer, you could read the excellent [2ality blog](http://2ality.com/2014/10/es6-promises-api.html):

> `then()` returns a new promise Q (created via the constructor of the receiver):
>   **If either of the reactions returns a value, Q is resolved with it.**
>   If either of the reactions throws an exception, Q is rejected with it.

You could read the brilliant [YDKJS](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/async%20%26%20performance/ch3.md):

> A thrown exception inside either the fulfillment or rejection handler of a then(..) call causes the next (chained) promise to be immediately rejected with that exception.

Answer (score -1):

You could move the chain into the conditional branch:

```
p.then((res) => {
  if(true) {
    return Promise.resolve(res + 2).then((res) => {
      // executed only when the condition is true
    });
  } else {
    // do something 
    // chain ends here
  }
});
```

Answer (score -6):

Just use something like: reject('rejected') 
in the else of the first task.

```
P
.then((res) => {
    if(true) {
        return res + 2
    } else {
        reject('rejected due to logic failure'    }
})
.then((res) => {
    // executed only when the condition is true
    console.log(res)
})
```

Alternatively u can also add a catch section to ur first task with .catch()
Hope this helps.

Comment: `reject` won't be defined here, as it is only available in the new Promise context This won't work, and pulling it out into a variable outside of the scope seems very un-promise like.

Comment: Not only is it not defined, the solution is wrong. Additional calls to `resolve` or `reject` (for the same promise) after one of them has been called are ignored.